# Configuring React-native with React-native-ble-plx

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I was following this guide: "https://blog.expo.io/so-you-want-to-build-a-bluetooth-app-with-react-native-and-expo-6ea6a31a151d"

At "3--IOS Setup" in first step, "pod install" I get this error I've got no idea why, I followed the exact guide.

```
Ibrahims-MacBook-Pro:MyCar ibrahim$ cd ./ios
Ibrahims-MacBook-Pro:ios ibrahim$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Pre-downloading: `ExpoKit` from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.5.10`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `React` from `../node_modules/react-native`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `react-native-ble-plx` from `../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx`
Fetching podspec for `yoga` from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `react-native-ble-plx-swift` depended upon by `react-native-ble-plx`
Ibrahims-MacBook-Pro:ios ibrahim$
```

This is the error

```
"[!] Unable to find a specification for `react-native-ble-plx-swift` depended upon by `react-native-ble-plx`"
```

Answer (score 3):

Open Podfile which is located inside ./ios folder and add this line

```
pod 'react-native-ble-plx-swift', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx'
```

Save it

Run `pod install`